# Android Display a notification into the statusbar without an expandable view

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I need help to do something.
I try to display a notification into the android statusbar.

It will inform the user that a synchronization with the server is in progress.

Now, I use this code and it works fine :

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = builder.getNotification();
    nm.notify(1, notif);
```

The only one problem is that a view is created when the user expand the statusbar. What I want to do is only display a small icon on the top of the status bar, without the contentview.

Anyone know how to do that ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I saw several answer from CommonsWare that say that it's not possible, but I also seen in several app (e.g. Yahoo Mail) that make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

The rationale is this: if the user looks at the status bar and sees an icon, she should have some way of figuring out what that icon means. Therefore there must be a row in the notification panel corresponding to each icon.

I suggest creating a notification that explains, just as you have done in your question, that a synchronization is in progress; this is a great opportunity to indicate which app is currently syncing (so if there's some kind of problem or the sync is taking forever the user knows which app needs attention).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I seen that Yahoo Mail makes a notification without an expendable view, so it's strange...

Comment: Really? It's really not possible to create an icon without a row in the notification shade. Can you point me to a screenshot or something?

Comment: I'm wrong with Yahoo Mail.. The icon display by Yahoo app is the sync icon, displayed by the OS.
I use a different way to notify the user while the app perform a server connection ;-) 

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to show notification icon on status bar

```
 private void showNotification() {
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the
    // expanded notification

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Service Started", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
    // notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.service_label),
            "Service Started", contentIntent);
    // Send the notification.
    // We use a layout id because it is a unique number. We use it later to
    // cancel.
    nm.notify(R.string.service_started, notification);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not what I want. 

Your code do the same thing that mine (and this way to instantiate a notification is deprecated). I don't want a view in the notification panel, but only the small icon in the statusbar 

If I don't put a view for the notification panel, this exception occurs : 

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.test.app.notification id=1 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 kind=[null])`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is possible for an InputMethodService, just use showStatusIcon(resource_name).
But I think this is not a good idea for anything except input services.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context = TutListDownloaderService.this
.getApplicationContext();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

create the notification:

```
Notification updateComplete = new Notification();
updateComplete.icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync;
updateComplete.tickerText = context.getText(R.string.notification_title);
updateComplete.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Create Pending Object:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,TutListActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
notificationIntent, 0);

String contentTitle = context.getText(R.string.notification_title).toString();
String contentText;
if (!result) {
Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "XML download and parse had errors");
contentText = context.getText(R.string.notification_info_fail).toString();
} else {
contentText = context.getText(
    R.string.notification_info_success).toString();
}
updateComplete.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

Finally show the notification to user:

```
notificationManager.notify(LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, updateComplete);
```